# Why do we need AppBarLayout when we are using CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

[image: CollapsingToolbarlayout in Appbarlayout]

Also, what's the difference between an appbar layout and a collapsing toolbar layout?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**AppBarLayout**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) is a vertical `LinearLayout` which implements many of the features of material designs app bar concept, namely scrolling gestures.

Children should provide their desired scrolling behavior through `setScrollFlags(int)` and the associated layout xml attribute: `app:layout_scrollFlags`.

This view depends heavily on being used as a direct child within a `CoordinatorLayout`. If you use `AppBarLayout` within a different `ViewGroup`, most of it's functionality will not work.

[**CollapsingToolbarLayout**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) is a wrapper for `Toolbar` which implements a collapsing app bar. It is designed to be used as a direct child of a `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: AndroidX [AppBarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout) and [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/CollapsingToolbarLayout)